# how to fix Unity 3d Jump animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I am new to Unity Game Development. I have a simple question but I am not getting the correct answer anywhere.
I had a player(capsule) that can jump and move. Now I have added a character to it and added animations. The walk and move animations are fine but...

My character is jumping as usual and over that, **the animation of jumping is playing** so It's looking like a double jump. What to do??

here is a video for better understand : [Problem Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oLV0rhQHsAZ2z9-QKOHAeyOYTrwOxo2o/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the animation the character is crouching in preparation before it does the actual jump. Seems like you could either start playing the animation and have an event in the animation that triggers the actual jump after the crouching is done. Or to avoid that delay, trim off or skip the crouching part from the front of the animation.

Comment: Your jump is instantaneous while the jump animation is not, they are out of sync, to what Josh says.